# How do I run a constant background service in android oreo?

Tags: java, android, service, android-8.0-oreo, beacon

I am scanning for BLE devices constantly. Now in android oreo the OS shuts down service automatically, is there a way to scan even after app is killed?

I have explored
1.) foreground service with notifications [a bad user experience]
2.) periodic job schedule [inefficient]
3.) using accessibility services [android sweeps apps that use it without helping disabled people] or is there a way to get prior approval for this?

If there is something I am missing let me know

Comment: Don't agree. In Android 8 you can configure your notification channel to set the priority to IMPORTANCE_MIN which means no sound, no vibration and no visible unless you open the notification center, so this doesn't disturb the user and the UX is not  affected. Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50454453/9771840

Comment: I don't think a foreground service can run with importance min, it just gets killed. @MarcEstrada

Comment: Right, I use an IntentService, which runs a few seconds. Didn't try with permanent service.

Answer (score 1):

For full-power scanning, **your summary of the options is accurate.**  I wrote a [blog post](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8) about this that weights the pros and cons of the different options.

In the [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) we have opted for using a JobScheduler by default.  This can run at most every 15 minutes in the background.  IMO, the timing is the real disadvantage of this approach.  The fact that it is a bit more heavy weight and less efficient is not significant given job startup only happens once every 15 minutes.

The library had also recently added support to optionally configure a [foreground service](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/663) to enable scanning more often.  For many use cases, the persistent notification is acceptable, although it is a real disadvantage for others.

Unfortunately, **Android has no whitelist or special approval process to get you around this limitation.**  Your only option would be if you were a device manufacturer and could customize the rules enforcement in your own custom Android version.

**One alternative you did not mention** that the Android Beacon Library uses is to use a new Android O API that lets you have scan results delivered via intent to a `BroadcastReceiver`.  This works well with a scan filter to wake up your app if a BLE packet of specific interest is detected.    But once one is detected. Your process isn't running while this scan is happening, but it can then run a background service for the regular 10 minute limit on Android 8 after such a detection takes place. The example below has results delivered to `MyBroadcastReceiver`.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 int result = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(filters, settings, pendingIntent);
```

By using a combination of the techniques described above, most bluetooth scanning apps can still work well on Android 8+.

Comment: I cannot use the job scheduler as exit and entry events are really important and time specific, however this broadcast receiver seems interesting, this would wake the app even if it had been killed right? and thanks again!